# Xcode How to move an image up and down animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hey im trying to move an imageview down to the middle of the screen then back up to the top . here is my code , right now it just moves to the middle and stays there .

```
-(void)lineGoBack
{
    //move diagonally down
    line.center = CGPointMake(line.center.x,
                              line.center.y-10);
    //start time for first method
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(LineMovement) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


//The LINE
-(void)LineMovement
{ 
    lineMovementOffset = CGPointMake(line.center.x, screenSizeY/2);

    //move diagonally up
    line.center = CGPointMake(line.center.x,
                              line.center.y+10);

    //start time for second method
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(lineGoBack) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't like using blocks based animations for chained animations - they tend to grow difficult to read. I would suggest using [keyframe animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW8). This also enables you to easily define a number of intermediary points to your animation, or add more advanced features to your animation, e.g. curves.

Here is an example of how you can animate a `UIView` linearly between three points.

```
CGPoint startPoint = (CGPoint){100.f, 100.f};
CGPoint middlePoint = (CGPoint){400.f, 400.f};
CGPoint endPoint = (CGPoint){600.f, 100.f};

CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, middlePoint.x, middlePoint.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration = 3.f;
animation.path = thePath;
[self.animatedView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
self.animatedView.layer.position = endPoint;
```

To do an infinite animation between two points, you could use the code below. Applying it to a `UIImageView` would work the same.

```
CGPoint startPoint = (CGPoint){100.f, 100.f};
CGPoint endPoint = (CGPoint){400.f, 400.f};

CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration = 3.f;
animation.path = thePath;
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
[self.animatedView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

Comment: how would i use your code to animate a imageview ? and in a endless loop so it doesn't it the whole game.

Comment: I have added an example of an infinite animation between two points. There is no difference between applying it to a UIView or a UIImageView.

Comment: Im sorry for being annoying , im quite new at objective-c , im confused at the line self.animateview because i don't know where do i name my uioutlet that i made for the imageview . Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey im trying to find out the y point while its animating , but when i do NSLOG , it only displays the same number , not the animation value of y

Answer (score 4):

I would propose to use `[UIView -animateWithDuration:animations:completion]` for that:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                 animations:^{

                     imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x, imageView.center.y + 10.0f);

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                                      animations:^{

                                          imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x, imageView.center.y - 10.0f);

                                      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                      }];
                 }];
```

See [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a).

Besides that: method names shouldn't start with an uppercase letter

Comment: +1. Use animation rather than a timing loop. You'll get both smoother animation and better app performance.

Comment: i tested the code , and seems to move up but not back down? and anyway to make this run the whole game , like in repeat , in till we tell it to stop?