# How can I trigger my animation after a specific segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I have an animation that is currently working. I followed this answer [Xcode How to move an image up and down animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425910/xcode-how-to-move-an-image-up-and-down-animation)

I was able to get the animation triggered with a button. What I really want is to trigger the animation after a specific segue. Is it possible to trigger this animation when I segue to a specific view in my storyboard?

The animation is in a method inside my `ViewController` implementation.

```
-(void)animatePicker
{

    NSLog(@"Animate");
    CGPoint startPoint = (CGPoint){100.f, 100.f};
    CGPoint middlePoint = (CGPoint){400.f, 400.f};
    CGPoint endPoint = (CGPoint){600.f, 100.f};

    CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, middlePoint.x, middlePoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.duration = 3.f;
    animation.path = thePath;
    [pickerCircle.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
    pickerCircle.layer.position = endPoint;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a -(void)viewDidAppear; method in your UIViewController and call your animation function there.

This function is called when UIViewController view has been created and has appeared as well.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
    [masterViewController animate];
}
```